# Various Device discovery methods in Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, discovery

Hi guys which are the various methods for discovering devices or desktop clients in windows phone 7?

I have used Udpanysourcemulticast client which only works in wi-fi. And there is no support for UDP broadcast in wp7. Then what else can I use for discovering devices in a network?

Comment: It only makes sense to do this over WiFi (after all, "the network" becomes "the phone network" when using a cellular connection), so what's the stumbling block?

Comment: I am connecting my desktop through ethernet to the same network to which my wp7 device is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a sspd discovery message using a udp socket, and then listen for the responses. I have used this method and it works great.
It is too much code to post but if you google "wp7 ssdp:discover" you should find several examples.

Comment: But this is not working between LAN and Wifi even though they are connected to same network. Any idea?